# Android - Google Map v2 - need update google play service on device

Tags: android, google-maps

i use SDK 21 and i develop on google map v2 when i want install apk on device , device need latest version of google play service.

My questions are:

1 - have android devices google play service defaultly
2 - is it true to ask customer to install this service ?
3 - if two question is yes , how can i embed this service on my project that i just notify customer to service installation and my project install this service by itself

Comment: google play service is default installed in all android devices

Answer (score 5):

> 1 - have android devices google play service default

No, not all devices have google play services installed by default.

> 2 - is it true to ask customer to install this service ?
>   3 - if two question is yes , how can i embed this service on my project that i
>   just notify customer to service installation and my project install
>   this service by itself

Normally you would check if the google play services are installed on the device with `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);`, and then display an error dialog where it links to google play services app on Google Play market.

Something like this:

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
   if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
   } else {
       Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
       finish();
   }
}
```

For more info you can take a look over this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Comment: yes, i checked that service is available or not , then you say that custormer must install googlPlayservice himself ? and i must not install it by my app

Comment: See this line: `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();`. It will display an error dialog saying that "This app won't run unless google play services are installed" and a button will be shown to download them from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

You need to seperate the Google play services you use for developing your application and imbeding your Google Maps API V2 with the package installed on user's device.

Once you have understood it, you can use the latest package to develop you application. In case the users that is trying to install you application on his phone but he doesn't has the latest version, he would be promted to install the last version from Google Play Store if it support on his phone.