# Google maps: can't see the map on the phone

Tags: android, google-maps

I've developed a small android app that uses google maps api v2.

On my device (Galaxy S1 I9000) everything works fine, so i sent an APK to my friend so he can test it and he installed it using: `adb install app.apk`, but when he opens the app, no map is showing (he is able to see the main screen, but when clicking a button that takes him to map screen he sees black).

What am i missing?

Comment: Is latest version of Google Play Service app installed on your friend phone ?

Comment: I think you can have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218961/android-google-map-v2-need-update-google-play-service-on-device)

Comment: @YeLinAung - That's the first thing i asked him to check, and yes he does, but still no luck :(

Comment: your friend phone's location services must be on

Comment: @ArshadParwez - I assume you mean GPS, but the map is currently static and everything is hardcoded (It's a demo) so no need for location services

Comment: Yes GPS. Google Maps v2 won't show up if location services are turned off. I had faced this problem once. Specially if you using this line of code `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: @ArshadParwez - that is correct if you are actually trying to get a real GPS provider, but like i said, all values are hardcoded and I'm able to run it on my phone with no GPS

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it :)

When i exported the APK via eclipse i created a new certificate, but when i signed with google maps service i provided the debug certificate that comes with ADT.

So google didn't recognize the certificate and blocked the service.