# How to show maps in an android app, if google play services is not installed on a phone

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to show google maps v2 in my android app. Is there any way to show the map even if google play services is not installed on device?

Comment: You need Google Play services , which includes the Google Maps Android.

Answer (score 5):

If the Google Play Services application is not installed on your user's device, you may fall back to other providers, e.g. [static maps from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) or [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Comment: But I have seen Google inbuilt "Maps" application working on the same device, even if the google play servcies is not installed. Are they using the same fallbacks as you mentioned above ?

Comment: @user2331595 Google Maps app doesn't use Google Play Services. They most probably have the same code (or even a superset of it) inside that app.

Comment: @user2331595 if you have seen devices running google maps without Google Play Services then they must be running Google Maps V1 which expired in Nov 2012

Answer (score 1):

No there is not since google maps is part of google play services. the only thing you can do is side-load google play services on the device or if the device has access to the play store you start an intent that takes them to where they can install it

Comment: Are there any other fallbacks, because I have seen google native maps application working in the same device where google play services is not installed...

Comment: a fallback would be to use `osmdroid` which uses `Open Street Maps`, The native google maps app does not use the v2 api and have their own implementation

Comment: I've got 2 devices where I have integrated google maps v2 and there most definitely isnt google play services installed. Device is running 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

[Android - Google Map v2 - need update google play service on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218961/android-google-map-v2-need-update-google-play-service-on-device)

You need google play services to show map, but follow the link for checking and downloading of google play services