# Google Maps Android V2: Failed to load maps module

Tags: android, google-maps, logcat, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing an application that makes use of the Google Maps API. However, when I run the application on an emulator, I get the following error: "Failed to load map module."

I made sure I checked "Google Maps API For Android" from the Developer's Console. The following are my configurations:

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="MYPACKAGE">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.


    -->

    <permission android:name="MYPACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where MY_API_KEY is the actual API key I received from Google.

activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MYPACKAGE.MainActivity" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package MYPACKAGE;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The LogCat shows me the following when I attempt to run the code:

```
02-12 03:57:57.370 1261-1261/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-12 03:57:59.030 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
02-12 03:57:59.040 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 240: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
02-12 03:57:59.040 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
02-12 03:57:59.090 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
02-12 03:57:59.090 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 542: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
02-12 03:57:59.100 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
02-12 03:57:59.520 1261-1293/com.be2015.meetupmap I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
02-12 03:57:59.680 1261-1293/com.be2015.meetupmap E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
02-12 03:57:59.700 1261-1293/com.be2015.meetupmap E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
02-12 03:58:00.240 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 338K, 12% free 3048K/3452K, paused 171ms, total 213ms
02-12 03:58:00.250 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap I/zzy: Making Creator dynamically
02-12 03:58:01.520 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.mz.b
02-12 03:58:01.520 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 141: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
02-12 03:58:01.520 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00ce
02-12 03:58:01.530 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.nb.a
02-12 03:58:01.530 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
02-12 03:58:01.530 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
02-12 03:58:01.630 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
02-12 03:58:01.680 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: module id not found
02-12 03:58:01.680 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 1 failed.
02-12 03:58:02.270 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: module id not found
02-12 03:58:02.270 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 2 failed.
02-12 03:58:02.370 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Failed to load module: module id not found
02-12 03:58:02.370 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Attempt 3 failed.
02-12 03:58:02.420 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
02-12 03:58:02.430 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 119 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
02-12 03:58:02.440 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
02-12 03:58:02.440 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
02-12 03:58:02.450 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 118 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
02-12 03:58:02.450 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
02-12 03:58:02.470 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
02-12 03:58:02.470 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 119 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
02-12 03:58:02.470 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
02-12 03:58:02.470 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
02-12 03:58:02.480 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 120 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
02-12 03:58:02.480 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
02-12 03:58:02.480 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/DynamiteUtils: Client module failure reason: 11
02-12 03:58:02.510 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/maps.CreatorImpl: Module could not be loaded.
02-12 03:58:02.570 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/maps.CreatorImpl: Failed to load maps module.
                                                                          android.os.RemoteException
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(SourceFile:76)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:96)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzh(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1129)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2283)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
                                                                      at com.be2015.meetupmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 03:58:03.310 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-12 03:58:03.350 1261-1261/com.be2015.meetupmap D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

[image: This is what I see in the emulator on opening the app]

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? I have absolutely no idea!

Comment: 1)Try Emulator with AVD of Google Api.  2) Did you start Google maps api from google developer consol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your problem?!

```
 int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
       if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
           GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
       } else {
           Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
           finish();
       }
    }
```

[Android - Google Map v2 - need update google play service on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218961/android-google-map-v2-need-update-google-play-service-on-device)